# Why does the answer come back as a infinite loop when calling function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

double weightConv(double w , string weightUnit)
{
    if (weightUnit == "g" || "G")
        cout << w * 0.035274 << "oz";
    else if (weightUnit == "oz" || "OZ" || "oZ" || "Oz")
        cout << w / 28.3495 << "g";
    else if (weightUnit == "kg" || "KG" || "Kg" || "kG")
        cout << w * 2.20462 << "lb";
    else if (weightUnit == "lb" || "LB" || "Lb" || "lB")
        cout << w / 0.453592 << "kg";
    else if (weightUnit == "ton" || "tn" || "TON" || "TN")
        cout << w * 1.10231 << "sh tn";
    else if (weightUnit == "sh tn" || "SH TN")
        cout <<  w / 0.90718 << "tn";
    else
        cout << "Invalid unit of measurement";

    return weightConv(w, weightUnit);
}// end of weightCov function


int main()
{
    string user;
    double mass;
    string unitType;

    cout << "Enter a mass and its unit type indicator(g,kg,lb,oz,ton,or sh tn)" << endl;
    cin >> mass >> unitType;


    // case sensitive characters
    //regex reg_icase("g", regex::icase);
    //if (regex_match("G", reg_icase))

    double answer = weightConv(mass, unitType);

// Output Results
    cout << " Mass = " << answer << endl;

    if (user == "exit")
    {
        return 0;
    }

}// end of main
```

For some odd reason when I input a number and a string through `cin` and try to print the answer out by calling the function `weightConv` it gives an infinite loop. Can someone please help me fix my code?

Answer (score 4):

It's infinite recursion: `weightConv()` calls itself.

Comment: Instead of recursively calling weightConv(), you could return a value say 0 (because the function double should return a value) and since you are already printing your answers in the function itself, you don't necessarily return anything and catch it in the main function.

Comment: Now that's a more precise answer I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is an unending recursion as `weightConv()` is calling itself again and again causing `Segmentation Fault`. Also, you never input the string `user`, hence, it should be removed or input after the `weightConv()` function.